# How to create a function that merges the first $n$-digits of each value in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, digits

Suppose we have a list of numbers. For example,

```
A={1231,1232,1233,1241,1236}
```

Using a function `f[x,A]`, I want to rearrange this list into a group of lists that contain the first digits (for `x=1`)

```
f[1,A]={1,2,3,1,6}
```

The first and second digits (for `x=2`)

```
f[2,A]={31,32,33,41,36}
```

The first, second, third digits (for `x=3`) and continuing until we cover the value in the original list with the most digits (`x=Max@@ IntegerLength/@A`).

(If there are zeros in the first digit, i.e `01` then the zeros must be ignored i.e `1`).

How do we proceed?

Comment: The OP can use terms such as "least significant digit" and "most significant digit" to remove this ambiguity caused by "first digit" etc. Please also mention if the numbers have the same number of digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod):

```
f[n_, list_] := Mod[list, 10^n]
```

Then:

```
f[1, A]
f[2, A]
f[3, A]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 6}

> {31, 32, 33, 41, 36}

> {231, 232, 233, 241, 236}

Answer (score 2):

```
f[n_, list_] := FromDigits /@ Reverse /@ (Take[#, UpTo[n]] & /@ Reverse /@ IntegerDigits /@ list)

B = {1, 12, 123, 1234, 10005}
Table[f[i, B], {i, 1, 5}]
(* 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
    {1, 12, 23, 34, 5}, 
    {1, 12, 123, 234, 5}, 
    {1, 12, 123, 1234, 5}, 
    {1, 12, 123, 1234, 10005}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1241, 1236, 1205};

ClearAll[f]
f[i_Integer, a_List] := FromDigits[ #[[-i;;]] ]& /@ IntegerDigits[a]

f[1, A]
(* Out: {1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5} *)

f[2, A]
(* Out: {31, 32, 33, 41, 36, 5} *)
```

Comment: you can also use the 3-argument form of `IntegerDigits`, that is, `FromDigits /@ IntegerDigits[a, 10, i]`

Comment: @kglr That's nice! I don't think I knew that form. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1241, 236, 5};
```

Using string-functions

```
f[n_][x_] := ToExpression @ StringTake[StringPadLeft[ToString /@ x], -n]

f[3] @ list
```

{231, 232, 233, 241, 236, 5}

```
f[#] @ list & /@ Range[4] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1241, 1236};
```

Using `TakeDrop`:

```
f[n_Integer, A_List] /; n == 1 := 
FromDigits@*First@TakeDrop[Reverse@#, n] & /@ IntegerDigits[A]

f[n_Integer, A_List] /; n > 1 := 
FromDigits@*Reverse /@ (First@TakeDrop[Reverse@#, n] & /@ IntegerDigits[A])

Table[f[n, A], {n, 1, 4}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_Integer?Positive, {m__Integer?Positive}] :=
 Module[{len = Max[Ceiling[Log10[{m}]]]},
  FromDigits[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[#], len][[-n ;;]]] & /@ {m}]

A = {1231, 1232, 1233, 1241, 001236, 12, 12006};

Table[f[n, A], {n, 1, Max[Ceiling[Log10[A]]]}] // Column
```

[image]